# Run Windows .cmd batch file commands asynchronously and capture the return codes

Tags: cmd

I can run multiple SAS invocations in sequence, capturing the return code after each invocation so that the 2nd invocation and beyond only run if the 1st invocation is error free, the 3rd and beyond only run if the 2nd is error free, and so on.

Here's the code for 2 invocations that works as desired.  (I'm not asking how to invoke SAS; what's below is syntactically correct).

I use `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` because I understand that it prevents all occurrences of errorlevel from being resolved at once.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM call 1st program
"C:\Program Files\SASHome_94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin c:\test1.sas -nosplash -nologo -nostatuswin -log 'c:\test1.log' -print 'c:\test1.txt'
if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
  set error_segment=test1.sas
  goto :errorabort
)
REM then call 2nd program if return code from 1st program was 0
"C:\Program Files\SASHome_94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin c:\test2.sas -nosplash -nologo -nostatuswin -log 'c:\test2.log' -print 'c:\test2.txt'
if !errorlevel! neq 0 (
  set error_segment=test2.sas
  goto :errorabort
)
exit /b
:errorabort
echo Error in program %error_segment% so script aborts
```

I want to run both invocations asynchronously and capture the return codes so that the 3rd invocation and beyond only run when both jobs are error free.  I've tried several things but nothing works.  Here's typical code.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
START "test1" "C:\Program Files\SASHome_94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin c:\test1.sas -nosplash -nologo -nostatuswin -log 'c:\test1.log' -print 'c:\test1.txt'
START "test2" "C:\Program Files\SASHome_94\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -sysin c:\test2.sas -nosplash -nologo -nostatuswin -log 'c:\test2.log' -print 'c:\test2.txt'
REM check the !errorlevel! from each invocation here, proceed if all are 0 else abort with message
echo errorlevel from asyncronous test is !errorlevel!
```

I don't see how to capture the return codes.  From testing where I use a sleep function in the SAS programs so they run for several minutes, I can see that the script falls through to the ECHO statement as soon as both invocations begin, and I get an errorlevel of 0 at that point.  While I'd ideally like to capture each of the return codes, I could live with capturing the highest return code if any were non-zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: The simple way would be to wrap `test1` and `test2` with a batch file. At the end of the batch file, write a file such as `test1done.txt` and `test2done.txt`. Use `START` on the two batch files, then have your main script wait until both `test1done.txt` and `test2done.txt` files exist. After they exist, start `test3`. This does not scale well. If you need a more generic solution to use in a variety of situations, you would need to develop something more sophisticated. Could be cmd, but I would do PowerShell which has capability to run jobs.

Comment: Take a look at [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and perhaps also [`waitfor`](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html)...